# Loop error skipping and go to next one (VBA)

Tags: vba, error-handling

I wanted to use errorhanlder as below.
On error handler, it simply click 'home button' and go to next one..

I thought after error handler, it will start from bot.wait 3000 but it goes to below code.

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//textarea[@name='tabview:tabform:createActivityPanel:j_id_id210pc20']", 3000).SendKeys Sheet1.Cells(X, 4)
```

i want the code after error handler to start from below code..

```
bot.Wait 3000


bot.FindElementById("headerForm:awbSearchText", 3000).SendKeys Sheet1.Cells(X, 1)
```

Of course, Row should be next one.. if there was error on row '2', it should go to error handler and start from '3'.

Using resume next is not option as it could result in serious tracing error even though i can finish loop.

```
Lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For X = 2 To Lastrow

    bot.Wait 3000
    
    
    bot.FindElementById("headerForm:awbSearchText", 3000).SendKeys Sheet1.Cells(X, 1)
    
    bot.Wait 2000
    
    bot.FindElementById("headerForm:searchBtnHidden", 3000).Click


    bot.Wait 3500
    
        Set eleAct = bot.FindElementById("headerForm:menuItems", 3500).AsSelect
        bot.Wait 2000
        eleAct.SelectByText "New Activity"
    
    bot.FindElementById("headerForm:goButton").Click
    

    bot.Wait 2500
    
        Set eleAct2 = bot.FindElementById("tabview:tabform:createActivityPanel:selectActivityType", 3000).AsSelect
        eleAct2.SelectByText "Request NCI"
        
    bot.Wait 2000
    
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='targetTypeInp']").Click
    
        Set eleORG = bot.FindElementById("tabview:tabform:createActivityPanel:NewActivityMap_originCode", 2000).AsSelect
        eleORG.SelectByValue Sheet1.Cells(X, 3)
       
    
    bot.Wait 1000
    
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//textarea[@name='tabview:tabform:createActivityPanel:j_id_id210pc20']", 3000).SendKeys Sheet1.Cells(X, 4)
    
    bot.Wait 2000
    
    bot.FindElementById("tabview:tabform:createActivityPanel:saveNewActivity").Click
    
    bot.Wait 3000

Next

Exit Sub

Errorhandler:

    bot.Wait 1500
    
    bot.FindElementById("tabview:j_id_id62:0:tabName", 2500).Click
       
    Err.Clear
    
    Resume Next
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is to Resume Next on Error. and then check if an Error occured via `Err.Number`.

```
For x = 2 to lastrow

    'skip line that raises error
    On Error Resume Next 
    
    'your main code

    'if any Error is raised
    If Err.Number > 0 Then 

        'your error handling

    End If

next x

'return to default error handling
On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: 'I did what you suggested but then every time i run the script, it executes error handling. Plus, i cannot put two 'next x' on error handler  as there is no 'For'

Comment: I changed my answer so that the error handling code does not get executed on every loop. Plus, i never said you should write `next x` two times.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But this cannot be used as it can lead the error on my webpage. It can ignore the line but will end up wrong result on webpage..i cannot use the resume next.. So it should go to error handler and after that it should start next x.

Answer (score 0):

I searched more and i found the solution for this.

```
On Error GoTo Errorhandler 'i put this before loop
    
 For x = 2 to lastrow
        
 'main code
        
     
Continue: 'this would allow error handler to jump to next loop
next x
        
Exit sub 'script will not read errorhandler after finishing loop
     
Errorhanlder:
    
error handled 
    
Err.clear 'not sure if this is necessary but i put it.
    
Resume Continue 'This will lead to next x
```